# String to JSON Path (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am trying to create a JavaScript function where I want to modify the object that I pass in and return that. I am able to create a string of the full path of the content that needs to be changed, but this is  string. How can I change this so that it recognises that it is a JSON Path?

Currently, it fails my if check as it's checking as a string, when I need it to check as a JSON Path.

```
var modifiedObj = function (content) {
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        var pathMaker = ["randonPath.one", "randonPath.two", "randonPath.three", "randonPath.four", "randonPath.five"];
        for (var j = 0; j < pathMaker.length; j++) {
            var pathValid = "content[" + i + "]." + pathMaker[j] + ".valid";
            var pathNotValid = "content[" + i + "]." + pathMaker[j] + ".notValid";
            if (pathValid !== undefined && pathNotValid == undefined) {
                pathNotValid = content.referenceAnotherField;
            };
        };
    };
    return content;
};
```

Any advise?

Comment: use brackets to step into each sub-object, bailing if it's undefined.

Comment: Backet from the string JSON Path?